# C# WPF DataContext не устанавливается в ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.View.WorkspaceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:view="clr-namespace:TestApp.View"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
        <view:TestView DataContext="{Binding TestViewModel}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"/>
</UserControl>
```

TestView ето UserControl, ContentPresenter показывает UserControl но в UserControl DataContext не находит, почему? Задача у меня изменять View в зависимости от типа DataContext

Comment: Судя по вашему профилю, вы не отмечаете ответы как принятые, пожалуйста, не забывайте комментировать ответы, если они вас по каким-то причинам не устраивают и принимать верные ответы. Для этого нужно нажать на галочку слева от ответа.